# Spring ignores Mongo settings in application.properties

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, spring-boot

I am trying to learn MongoDB with Spring. When I try to write to the db it works but everything goes to the `test` database. Here is how my application.properties file looks like:

```
spring.data.mongodb.host=localhost
spring.data.mongodb.port=27017
spring.data.mongodb.username=
spring.data.mongodb.password=
spring.data.mongodb.database=pets
```

The records are supposed to go to the database `pets`, but they all go to `test`. Any idea why? I have no other configurations. Even when I comment out all those settings, it still works and writes to `test`, which makes me think that they are just being ignored. I have no password and username set up.

Thanks

Comment: can the post the code of your configuration class

Comment: i do not have one. The only configuration i have is in the application.properties file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For some reason, I solved it by defining a MongoConfig and setting the database name there. Apparently, it is deprecated, but it works...